# Why is 'Bearer' required before the token in 'Authorization' header in a HTTP request?

Tags: http, authentication, authorization, token, bearer-token

What exactly is the difference between following two headers:

```
Authorization : Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr

           vs

Authorization : cn389ncoiwuencr
```

All the sources which I have gone through, sets the value of 'Authorization' header as 'Bearer' followed by the actual token. However, I have not been able to understand the significance of it. What if I simply put the token in the Authorization header?

Answer (score 2):

Then the service receiving the header would not know how to interpret it. Instead of `bearer`, it could also be `basic` for example in which case the encoded string is a base64 encoded username/password instead of a token.

There are a number of authentication schemes possible. Which one is used is indicated by the identifier in the header.

Comment: Sorry MvdD, I am still confused. If I am only writing the service, I know how to interpret it right without the identifier also. So, is writing the identifier some kind of a convention which is better to follow? Because even if I don't write the identifier and I am only writing the service, I will know how to interpret the token.

Comment: But then you're using a custom protocol you made up yourself.

Comment: Right, but then you should use a custom header. You can do whatever you want if you create your own header. If you go with the standard `Authorization` header, you should follow the standard and start with a scheme identifier.